# WCF client. Checking for certificate in cert store. Is this a good way to ensure only certain clients can connect to service?

Tags: wcf, ssl, certificate

I have a small challenge with securing an application. My knowledge is very limited in this area so I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.

I have a WCF service running in IIS and two different client-applications talking to this service. Lets call these applications AppNotSoSecure and AppReallySecure. 
The communication between applications and the service is already secured using SSL and username/password exchange.

Now the customer request that the security of one of these applications - AppReallySecure - should be increased by ensuring that this application can only be accessed (run) on certain machines approved by our operations department.

I am considering issuing a certificate that can be installed on these machines and simply check for the certificate thumbprint when starting AppReallySecure. I would of course ensure that the certificate is set to not be exportable and require a private key for installation.

Can anyone comment on this approach?

Thanks

Comment: How would you get the thumbprint? Do you mean you'd set up your IIS server to require a client SSL certificate? And setting a certificate so it can't be exported is just window dressing - any application that needs to use the certificate has to have full access to it, so it's trivial to work around any "You can't export this" setting.  Once you give out a client certificate - you give out the client certificate and lose control of it. If you give it to the customer, and then use that certificate to verify access, that customer is responsible for what happens to that certificate.  End of story.

Comment: In my opinion, Use certificate to authenticate the client is good idea. Please refer to the below link. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/message-security-with-a-certificate-client To ensure that you only communicate with a specific machine, we need to issue a certificate to the machine with a specific domain name, and then establish a two-way trust. During the process of authentication, the certificate is used as the client’s credentials

Comment: @AndrewHenle. I feared that the solution would not be sufficient. Thanks for providing me with the explanation. 
I am trying to avoid setting IIS up to require a client certificate. The problem is that both applications use the same WCF services running in the same website.

Comment: You could [sign the messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688819/how-to-sign-wcf-message-with-certificate-using-https-transport-with-client-certi) using WCF the mechanisms.